# C File descriptor duplication without sharing offset or flags

Tags: c, linux, windows, file, descriptor

I need to concurrently read from a file in different offsets using C.
`dup` unforunately creates a file descriptor that shares offset and flags with the original.

Is there a function like `dup` that does not share the offset and flags?

*EDIT* I only have access to the file pointer `FILE* fp;` I do not have the file path

*EDIT* This program is compiled for windows in addition to mac and many flavors of linux

*SOLUTION*
We can use pread on posix systems, and I wrote a pread function for windows which solves this problem
https://github.com/Storj/libstorj/blob/master/src/utils.c#L227

Comment: `open()` the file twice?

Comment: I only have access to a file pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use pread and pwrite on POSIX systems, and I wrapped ReadFile/WriteFile on Windows Systems into pread and pwrite functions

```
#ifdef _WIN32
ssize_t pread(int fd, void *buf, size_t count, uint64_t offset)
{
    long unsigned int read_bytes = 0;

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    overlapped.OffsetHigh = (uint32_t)((offset & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LL) >> 32);
    overlapped.Offset = (uint32_t)(offset & 0xFFFFFFFFLL);

    HANDLE file = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd);
    SetLastError(0);
    bool RF = ReadFile(file, buf, count, &read_bytes, &overlapped);

     // For some reason it errors when it hits end of file so we don't want to check that
    if ((RF == 0) && GetLastError() != ERROR_HANDLE_EOF) {
        errno = GetLastError();
        // printf ("Error reading file : %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    return read_bytes;
}

ssize_t pwrite(int fd, const void *buf, size_t count, uint64_t offset)
{
    long unsigned int written_bytes = 0;

    OVERLAPPED overlapped;
    memset(&overlapped, 0, sizeof(OVERLAPPED));

    overlapped.OffsetHigh = (uint32_t)((offset & 0xFFFFFFFF00000000LL) >> 32);
    overlapped.Offset = (uint32_t)(offset & 0xFFFFFFFFLL);

    HANDLE file = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(fd);
    SetLastError(0);
    bool RF = WriteFile(file, buf, count, &written_bytes, &overlapped);
    if ((RF == 0)) {
        errno = GetLastError();
        // printf ("Error reading file :%d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }

    return written_bytes;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 3):

On Linux, you can recover the filename from `/proc/self/fd/N`, where `N` is the integral value of the file descriptor:

```
sprintf( linkname, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fd );
```

Then use `readlink()` on the resulting link name.

If the file has been renamed or deleted, you may be out of luck.

But *why* do you need another file descriptor?  You can use `pread()` and/or `pwrite()` on the original file descriptor to read/write from/to the file without affecting the current offset.  (caveat:  on Linux, `pwrite()` to a file opened in append mode is buggy - POSIX states that `pwrite()` to a file opened in append mode will write to the offset specified in the `pwrite()` call, but the Linux `pwrite()` implementation is broken and will ignore the offset and append the data to the end of the file - [see the BUGS section of the Linux man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pread.2.html))

Comment: Is there a windows equivalent for this too? I compile the program for many different OS's

Comment: @AlexanderLeitner  This might be relevant (I don't have enough in-depth Windows programming experience to be sure):  [GetFinalPathNameByHandle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364962%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

No, neither C nor POSIX (since you mention `dup()`) has a function for opening a new, independent file handle based on an existing file handle.  As you observed, you can `dup()` a file descriptor, but the result refers to the same underlying open file description.

To get an independent handle, you need to `open()` or `fopen()` the same path (which is possible only if the `FILE` refers to an object accessible through the file system).  If you don't know what path that is, or if there isn't any in the first place, then you'll need a different approach.

Some alternatives to consider:

- buffer some or all of the file contents in memory, and read as needed from the buffer to serve your needs for independent file offsets;
- build an internal equivalent of the `tee` command; this will probably require a second thread, and you'll probably not be able to read one file too far ahead of the other, or to seek in either one;
- copy the file contents to a temp file with a known name, and open that as many times as you want;
- if the FILE corresponds to a regular file, map it into memory and access its contents there.  The POSIX function `fmemopen()` could be useful in this case to adapt the memory mapping to your existing stream-based usage.

Comment: A temporary linux only solution also seems to be something like 
`sprintf(path, "/proc/self/fd/%d", fileno(state->original_file));` the main reason I am doing this because I stopped writing any files to disk These are up files of to many gigabytes of data so I'll have to look into memory mapped files it seems.

Answer (score 1):

On windows (assuming VisualStudio), you can get access to the OS file handle from the stdio FILE handle.
From there, reopen it and convert back to a new FILE handle.

This is windows only, but I think Andrews answer will work for Linux and probably the Mac as well - unfortunately there is no portable way to have it work on all systems.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <io.h>  
#include <stdio.h>

FILE *jreopen(FILE* f)
{
    int n = _fileno(f);
    HANDLE h = (HANDLE)_get_osfhandle(n);
    HANDLE h2 = ReOpenFile(h, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0);
    int n2 = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)h2, _O_RDONLY);
    FILE* g = _fdopen(n2, "r");

    return g;
}
```